# how to filter pandas dataframe on the basis of condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which is built from a table with unique t_id and s_id and I want to drop the records from this dataframe for the t_id's that has country_date null for all of the s_id's.

data like:

```
t_id s_id country_date
T1   S1   jan
T1   S2   mar
T2   S1   
T2   S2
T3   S2   jan
T3   S3
```

result :

```
t_id s_id country_date
T1   S1   jan
T1   S2   mar
T3   S2   jan
T3   S3
```

i have written the below line but that's wrong:

```
raw_data.groupby("t_id").country_date.max().notnull()
```

Please could you provide the way to filter dataframe records on the above criteria.Also, print the t_ids that are filtered out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isnull` and `all`:

```
df.groupby('t_id').filter(lambda x: ~x.country_date.isnull().all())
```

If those blanks are '' and not NaN you might need to:

```
df.replace('',pd.np.nan).groupby('t_id').filter(lambda x: ~x.country_date.isnull().all())
```

Output:

```
  t_id s_id country_date
0   T1   S1          jan
1   T1   S2          mar
4   T3   S2          jan
5   T3   S3          NaN
```

And, to see those ids that were dropped:

```
df.groupby('t_id').filter(lambda x: x.country_date.isnull().all())['t_id'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['T2'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: hi scott..thanks again :) and way to print the t_id records that are dropped ? not the one's that are kept..

Comment: Noticed, i just removed the negation sign (~) to get the other records and added ['t_id'].unique()

Comment: `df.filter(lambda x: ~x.country_date.astype(bool).all())` `bool('')` evaluates to `False`... great answer :-)